# How to install ReviewBoard as a non-root user on Redhat Linux?

Tags: linux, redhat, review-board

The official installation guide (https://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/dev/admin/installation/linux/) requires the user login as root or is using sudo. I don't have them and want to install a local copy under my home directory. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can install it without permissions. I have checked the link you posted and the packages mentioned there will need root's permission to install them.